# Need help figuring out how to code NavigationView pages in WinRT

Tags: c++, xaml, uwp, windows-runtime

Let me first state how frustrated I am in not being able to find many examples that are written in C++ for UWP/WinRT. I need to be able to reference and use shared .H files, so C# is not very useful. And guess what, almost all the examples I found are in C#. I am no dummy, but I don't always know the conversion code from C# to C++.

I have Googled for the information I seek, searched for books, and read some web pages, but I have failed in finding the info I seek, so now I ask you (the coders that will know) how to solve my problem or where I might find the answers.

Here is the problem in a nutshell, I need the code for the NavigationView UI control in UWP written in C++. I followed the C# examples as best I could, but my code does not compile nor is it complete. There are 3 functions that I need to complete but I can't get them converted. I can give you any code file you want, but only give the 2 that pertain right now. Just ask if you need me to clarify something.

XAML file

```
    <Page
x:Class="Kcam_GUI_Test.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Kcam_GUI_Test"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="#FFB0B0B0"
Foreground="#FF000000">


<NavigationView x:Name="NavView"
                PaneDisplayMode="Top"
                IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed"

                SelectionChanged="NavView_SelectionChanged">

    <NavigationView.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TopNavigationViewItemForegroundPointerOver" Color="Black"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TopNavigationViewItemBackgroundPointerOver" Color="#FF005BAF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TopNavigationViewItemForegroundSelected" Color="Black"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TopNavigationViewItemBackgroundSelected" Color="#FF005BAF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TopNavigationViewItemForegroundSelectedPointerOver" Color="Black"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TopNavigationViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver" Color="#FF005BAF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TopNavigationViewItemForegroundPressed" Color="Black"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TopNavigationViewItemBackgroundPressed" Color="#FF005BAF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TopNavigationViewItemForegroundSelectedPressed" Color="Black"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TopNavigationViewItemBackgroundSelectedPressed" Color="#FF005BAF"/>
    </NavigationView.Resources>
    <NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <NavigationViewItem x:Name="OperationNav" Content="Operation" Tag="NavOperation" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <NavigationViewItem x:Name="AdminNav" Content="Administration" Tag="NavAdmin" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <NavigationViewItem x:Name="AdvancedNav" Content="Advanced" Tag="NavAdvanced" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <NavigationViewItem x:Name="FactoryNav" Content="Factory" Tag="NavFactory" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    </NavigationView.MenuItems>
    <StackPanel>
        <Rectangle Height="25">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF005BAF"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFB0B0B0" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Frame x:Name="NavFrame" Margin="0,5,0,0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Height="1000">
            <Slider Width="200" Height="50" Maximum="100" StepFrequency="10" TickPlacement="Inline" />
        </Frame>
  
    </StackPanel>

</NavigationView>
```

And just the 3 C++ functions that are causing me grief. Only one function is referenced in the XAML file.

```
        // This code is for when the NavigationView is clicked so it selects the correct page to navigate to.
void MainPage::NavView_SelectionChanged(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewSelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.IsSettingsSelected() == true)
    {
        NavView_Navigate("settings", args.RecommendedNavigationTransitionInfo());       // Notice the 1st param is not a string. Item is better, I think.
    }
    else if (args.SelectedItemContainer() != NULL)
    {
        std::string navItemTag = args.SelectedItemContainer();
        NavView_Navigate(navItemTag, args.RecommendedNavigationTransitionInfo());       // Notice the 1st param is not a string. Item is better, I think.
    }
}

// This function is responsible for loading each page. The commented code below this function was the first attempt.
void MainPage::NavView_Navigate(NavigationViewItem item, NavigationTransitionInfo transitionInfo)
{
    {
        switch (item.Tag())
        {
        case "NavOperation":
            NavFrame.Navigate(xaml_typename<Kcam_GUI_Test::OperationNavPage>());
            break;

        case "NavAdmin":
            NavFrame.Navigate(xaml_typename<Kcam_GUI_Test::AdminNavPage>());
            break;

        case "NavAdvanced":
            NavFrame.Navigate(xaml_typename<Kcam_GUI_Test::AdvancedNavPage>());
            break;

        case "NavFactory":
            NavFrame.Navigate(xaml_typename<Kcam_GUI_Test::FactoryNavPage>());
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    
    
    /*Type _page = null;

    if (navItemTag == "settings")
    {
        _page = xaml_typename<Kcam_GUI_Test::SettingsPage>();
    }
    else
    {
        var item = _pages.FirstOrDefault(p = > p.Tag.Equals(navItemTag));
        _page = item.Page;
    }
    // Get the page type before navigation so you can prevent duplicate
    // entries in the back stack.
    var preNavPageType = ContentFrame.CurrentSourcePageType;

    // Only navigate if the selected page isn't currently loaded.
    if (!(_page is null) && !Type.Equals(preNavPageType, _page))
    {
        ContentFrame.Navigate(_page, null, transitionInfo);
    }*/
}

// This function is either C# or VB. It is what gets called when the page loads. It selects the first NavigationView.
void MainPage::NavView_Loaded(Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Set the initial SelectedItem.
    for each(NavigationViewItemBase item in NavView.MenuItems)                      // This line is wrong
    {
        if (item is NavigationViewItem && item.Tag.ToString() == "NavOperation")    // This line is wrong
        {
            NavView.SelectedItem = item;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't expect you to tell me the answers directly, but any known examples of how this is done in C++ would be helpful. And If you could recommend a book to purchase that would cover UWP/WinRT in C++ (NO C#), I would be very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/navigationview) is navigationView  document that you could refer to(code with c++ winrt).

Comment: I did finally find the C++ example code and get my code fixed, although it was buried in the link Nico gave me. I am happy now. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, if you have the solution, please feel free post your answer below, and you could mark yourself.